# How to properly use enum in column mapping

Tags: database-design, enums

Let's say we have 2 entities (User and Profile):

```
User {
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    STATUS CHAR(5) NOT NULL
}
Profile {
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    STATUS CHAR(5) NOT NULL
}
```

I would map my entities like:

```
public class User {
    @Id private Integer id;
    private Status status;
}
public class Profile {
    @Id private Integer id;
    private Status status;
}
public enum Status {
    ACTIVE, INACTIVE, BLOCKED, SUSPENDED, PENDING;
}
@Converter( autoApply = true )
public class StatusConverter implements AttributeConverter<Status,String> {
    // Converter methods omitted for brevity
}
```

Since it works, I believe everything is alright until now.
Some status are equivalent in many entities, like ACTIVE, but there's some status that aren't equals to another entity status. For example a user can have the status BLOCKED, but we never have a blocked Profile (but we have a INACTIVE one).

Now I have some questions I would like your help:

1. Should I create one enum per entity (like UserStatus and ProfileStatus) so each one have it's own set of "status"? If yes, where should I place the enum? Inside the User entity (`User.Status`) or some specific package (`com.example.enums.UserStatusEnum`)?
2. Should I map it like a table `Status { ID INT NOT NULL, CODE CHAR(5) }` and let the application manage it? Or even create a new column (`ENTITY CHAR(5)`) to specify which entity that status corresponds to?
3. Change the enum to have one attribute to specify it's entities?

I don't see clearly what path I should follow. Do you have another suggestion?

Please, have in mind that there can be more entities, each one with a different set of Status. But these status don't change often, so I don't really believe I need a table on my database.

Answer (score 0):

Design the entities from the application side only. Then design a matching database schema to persist them - so the database is totally subordinate to the application.

Avoid "reusing" entities like status. Perhaps today the statuses of different entities align, but tomorrow they won't. Also, some entities may only be allowed to have a subset of statuses. You'll quickly descend into a mess. And to save what? A few rows and a couple of tiny tables. Not worth it.

Create separate enums, eg `UserStatus`. Ignore the fact that some status values are shared between entities.

Comment: Thank you for your help! 
But I am a bit confused. In your second paragraph I understood you're telling me to use many tables, one for each status I need. But in the next one you said to use multiple enums. Which approach is better?

Also, if using enums, how should I code it? One enum inside it's entity? Or a big package with many enums? Are there a design pattern for it?

Comment: do you have anything more to add to your answer? Do you have another advice based on my last comment in your answer?

Comment: @MiguelKVidal you need both more enums and more tables (a table for each enum). I would not put the enum inside a class. Just put them in the same package as your other model classes.

Comment: Still not clear: Enum or Table? Or a "enum in a table"? If it's the last option, how should I "map" it?